# How to parse JavaScript content with XPath

Tags: javascript, xpath

How to parse data-attributes embedded in both Html and JavaScript?

```html
    <h2 data-my-color="#333"></h2>
    <div data-my-color="#222"></div>
    <div data-my-color="#111"></div>
    <script>
    markup += '<p data-my-color="#444"></p>';
    </script>
```

With

```js
var result = document.evaluate('//*[starts-with(name(@*), "data-my-")]', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```

Data attribute in JavaScript is not parsed.

Is this normal or is the predicate incorrect?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a [specific API for working with data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) so no XPath would be needed.

Comment: It's normal. The JavaScript code is, to the HTML parser, just text in the `<script>` element.

Comment: You would have to special-case the `script` elements to use something like `script[contains(text(), "data-my-")]`. The real questions are: a) why do you want to do this and b) why do you want to do this with XPath in particular?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this may be what you are looking for:

```
var result = document.evaluate('//div/@data-my-color', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
for(var i = 0; i < result.snapshotLength; i++) {
  let node = result.snapshotItem(i);
  console.log(node.textContent);
}
```

Output:

```
"#222"
"#111"
```